# получить изображение с камеры

Tags: android, android-fragment, камера

Есть фрагмент 1 в нем imageView, кликаю на него открывается камера, после открывается фрагмент работающий с камерой, и после того как фото сделано происходит возврат обратно на фрагмент 1, пытаюсь отобразить фото в imageview но не срабатывает.
пример кода:
фрагмент 1.

```
FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = manager.beginTransaction();
    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.replace(R.id.content, new Photo());
    ft.commit();
```

фрагмент 2.

```
 public void nextStep() {
    preview.removeView(mPreview);
    mCamera.release();
    fragment1.makePhoto.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(currentFile));
    FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
    manager.popBackStack();
}
```

я так понимаю что у меня происходит вызов фрагмента из стека, а на нем фото нет, и поэтому не отображается, но как реализовать задуманное не понимаю. подскажите